# Æ ligature – the definitive answer

Tags: spelling, orthography, declinatio-prima

I have tried a search on the internet, but did not find anything official. I am looking for the definitive explanation of the symbol "æ" in Latin. Is it equivalent to the diphthong "ae" or is it different?

So is "Curriculum vitae" = "Curriculum vitæ"?

Comment: I'm intrigued as to what you do and don't consider 'official', if this site counts as the latter!

Comment: @dbmag9 As far as hearing it from just some person online goes, I think our site has the best just some persons. Now that's essentially official.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta To be clear, I consider this site very reliable and upvoted your answer! I just found it a funny turn of phrase from the OP.

Comment: @dbmag9 That's how I took it. I just wanted to say in an unnecessarily convoluted manner that this site is among the most reliable ones about Latin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When it comes to Latin, 'æ' is the same as 'ae', at least when in the diphthong.
When the vowels are in different syllables, as in *aer*, then 'æ' is not used.

You could see this so that 'ae' is such a commonly appearing combination that it is essentially a single letter.
It makes thus sense to write the two letters as one, and it also has the benefit of indicating that it is indeed a diphthong.
From a Latin point of view 'æ' is typically understood as a ligature, not a letter, but that is a mere matter of definition.

In some languages (at least many Nordic ones) 'æ' is a separate letter and is not interchangeable with 'ae'.
In Latin you can always write 'æ' out as 'ae', and thus indeed *Curriculum vitae* equals *Curriculum vitæ*.
The ligature should be applied consistently: either use it in all possible instances or never.
In the texts I have seen it is more common to never use ligatures, and non-diphthongs can be indicated by dieresis as in *aër*.

The same applies to the ligature 'œ' for 'oe' in Latin, but its use in other languages is different from 'æ'.

Comment: do you have a source for the claim that æ was only used for the diphthong?

Comment: @Tristan Unfortunately nothing but my experience. Judging by the votes, many users agree, but I know full well that that is not the most compelling proof. Probably the best course of action is to ask a separate question for a reputable source discussing this very point.