# Does, "Apostolus Hiberniae" end in an "ae" ligature or are the letters separate?

Tags: vocabulary

Could someone help me with the Latin translation of, "Apostle of Ireland"? I have found, "Apostolus Hiberniae". Does "Hiberniae" have end in the "æ" ligature or are the "a" and "e" separate?  I am painting an icon of St. Patrick for an older Catholic. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 12):

The letters *a* and *e* are in the same syllable (and are pronounced as a diphthong in some eras and dialects) in the word *Hiberniae*.
They can be written separately or as the ligature æ without any change in meaning or pronunciation.
The ligature is only an option when the two vowels are in the same syllable.

In church art it is very common to use the ligature when possible (thanks for the comment cmw!), so in that use context it would indeed be preferable to use it and spell the word as *Hiberniæ*.
It is a matter of style and preference, and arguably neither option is wrong.

For more details on *æ* and *ae*, see [this old question on comparing the two in various cases](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/14927/79).

Comment: I will say that the ligature is very frequent in church art, and so should probably be preserved if one is paying homage to that style.

Comment: @cmw Thanks! Updated. I'm less familiar with church art, but my vague recollection agrees.